# Declaring a type from a literal statement

Tags: swift, firebase

Implementing some firebase code in swift and I needed to promote a local variable to a class property but I don't know what type to declare it.

```
var myInfo:Any //what type should this be declared as?  [String: Any]? Dictionary or NSDictionary?

self.myInfo =  ["uid": "xyz", "neighborhoodId": "sesame street", "avatar":[],"location":[]]
```

What should I be declaring the type of myInfo as?

This is the Firebase method that I'll be passing `myInfo` into to set value:

[`- (void)setValue:(id)value`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_setValue)

Comment: The method signature you linked to would translate to the Swift type `AnyObject`.  

The documentation seems pretty terrible, as it makes no comment on what sorts of values it expects.  I don't know what exactly Firebase is or does or what sorts of values you should set here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare `myInfo` as `NSDictionary`, but the Swift way to do it is to declare `myInfo` as:

```
var myInfo:[String: AnyObject] = [:]
```

`[:]` creates an empty dictionary (0 key/value pairs) as an initial value for `myInfo`.  Then you can reassign it later:

```
myInfo = ["uid": "xyz", "neighborhoodId": "sesame street", "avatar":[],"location":[]]
```

---

Alternatively, you can create and initialize `myInfo` like this:

```
var myInfo = [String: AnyObject]()
```

This has the same effect, and it is just a matter of style and taste which one you use.  You will see both styles of initialization used.

Comment: yup that worked, is there a difference between [String: AnyObject]() and [:] and if so why would I use one vs the other.